# Trouble with adding Bcrypt repository

Tags: java, gradle, bcrypt

I'm trying to add bcrypt dependency. I found that I should add it this way but what I should paste here ? From where i can access repository ?

```
maven{
        url ""
    }
```

Source code

```
plugins {
        id 'java'
    }
    
    group 'org.example'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven{
            url ""
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4'
        implementation 'at.favre.lib.crypto:bCrypt:0.4.1'
    
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
        testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    }
    
    
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

I got message below:

```
> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
>    > Could not find at.favre.lib.crypto:bCrypt:0.4.1.
>      Searched in the following locations:
>        - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/at/favre/lib/crypto/bCrypt/0.4.1/bCrypt-0.4.1.pom
>      If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to
> adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
>      Required by:
>          project :
> 
> Possible solution:
>  - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure its `at.favre.lib::bCrypt::0.4.1`, not `at.favre.lib.crypto`. Also, current version is 0.10.2; 0.4.1 is from 2018, and not used. More generally it doesn't sound right to have *both* at.favre.lib and org.mindrot's - you pick one of them.